# PHP Extensions Are Not Enabled

Tags: yum, php, shared-library

I am running RHEL 7 and I am trying to use PHP 8.1. PHP is installing and the extensions are installed (per-Yum) but not enabled per-PHP.

- For example, if I run `php -m | grep dom` from the command line I will get no results returned.
- If I run `sudo yum install php81-php-dom` then `yum` returns

  ```
  Package php81-php-xml-8.1.6-1.el7.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version.
  ```
- I can use `locate` to see that there is a `.so` file for `dom` at `/opt/remi/php81/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/dom.so`.
- There is an `ini` file at `/etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-dom.ini`.
- I have tried creating a softlink between `/etc/opt/remi/php81/php.d/20-dom.ini` and `/etc/php.d/` (because I think that is where the ini file needs to be) and PHP returns

  ```
  HP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'dom'
  (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/dom (/usr/lib64/php/modules/dom: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory),
          /usr/lib64/php/modules/dom.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/dom.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory))
  in Unknown on line 0
  ```

I am not sure what I need to do to get this extension and others to be available for PHP. I also tried 8.0.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe that you also have other php versions installed and the `php` executable is linked with some other version than 8.1 What does `php -v` show? Can you also try `php81 -m | grep dom`

Comment: @ttsakpc I think you were right. I had deleted the last machine with this problem but I tried again with just sudo yum install -y --enablerepo=remi-php80 php  rather than also including php-cli.  I am then adding all the extensions with sudo yum install php80-php-{cli,bcmath,curl,date,dom,gd,json,mbstring,pdo,simplexml,xml,zip} -y. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, that was not the problem my test did not check the dom library that still appears not to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

You are confused by php80-php-* packages, designed for parallel installation of multiple versions (Software Collections) and php-* packages for default installation.

As explained in the [FAQ](https://blog.remirepo.net/pages/English-FAQ#scl)

For a proper repository configuration, follow the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).

So if you need dom extension for base installation

```
yum install php-dom
```

if you need pgsql and mysqli extensions for SCL installation

```
yum install php80-php-pgsql php80-php-mysqli
```

P.S. also a kind reminder that EL-7 is now very old (8 years) and that newer distributions (EL-8 or EL-9) are better to run modern software, such as recent PHP versions.

Answer (score 0):

Having similar problem with install php-pgsql / php-mysql extension on CentOs 8.

```
php artisan migrate
```

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pgsql.dll' (tried: /opt/remi/php80/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pgsql.dll (/opt/remi/php80/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pgsql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/remi/php80/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pgsql.dll.so (/opt/remi/php80/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/php_pgsql.dll.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

Solved this for php 8.0 with command

```
yum install php80-php-pgsql
```

Answer (score 0):

[Thanks to Remi Collet](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/713366/84244) for clearing up the confusion between installing PHP extensions for single PHP installations and multiple version PHP installations.

In this case, on AlmaLinux 8 (Centos 8 compatible) system, with a single PHP installation, logged in as `root` user.

First verify single PHP installalation:

```
> locate bin/php
/usr/bin/php
/usr/bin/php-cgi
/usr/bin/phpize
/usr/sbin/php-fpm
```

Indeed, a single PHP installation.

For additional troubleshooting, determine the location of the PHP extension modules and configuration files. Searching `/etc/php.ini` reveals:

```
;;;;
; Note: packaged extension modules are now loaded via the .ini files
; found in the directory /etc/php.d; these are loaded by default.
;;;;
```

Notice PHP is looking in `/etc/php.d` for an extension module configuration file. Attempt to list the extension module and it's configuration file:

```
> ls -la /usr/lib64/php/modules/ | grep dom.so
> ls -la /etc/php.d/ | grep dom.ini
```

Is there a config file in the `/etc/php.d` directory? If so, read it to see what directory PHP is looking for the extension in, and compare that to `/usr/lib64/php/modules/dom.so`.

If there is no config file for that extension in `/etc/php.d` that's why PHP is not loading the extension.

There are two options if you have a version specific extension loaded, 1) (not recommended) is to move the config file to the `/etc/php.d` directory and make sure it points to the module location, or, 2) (recommended) is to remove the previous extension installation and use the proper repository and package to install it.

**To properly install a PHP extension module for single PHP installation...**

...start by listing the system's current repo status (in pertinent part):

```
> dnf repolist all
repo id    repo name                                                  status
apprepo    apprepo                                                    enabled
appstream  AlmaLinux 8 - AppStream                                    enabled
baseos     AlmaLinux 8 - BaseOS                                       enabled
epel       Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64             enabled
extras     AlmaLinux 8 - Extras                                       enabled
powertools AlmaLinux 8 - PowerTools                                   enabled
remi       Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64      disabled
remi-safe  Safe Remi's RPM repository for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64 enabled
```

Is PowerTools enabled? (AlmaLinux 8 comes with powertools installed.)

```
powertools AlmaLinux 8 - PowerTools                                   enabled
```

...yes. However, if not enabled:

```
> dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools
```

Is `epel` repo installed and enabled? In this case yes, but if not:

```
> dnf install epel-release
```

Is `remi` repo installed and enabled? In this case yes, but if not:

```
> dnf install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-8.rpm
> dnf config-manager --set-enabled remi
```

Now simply:

```
> dnf install php-dom
> systemctl restart nginx
> systemctl restart php-fpm
```

And verify:

```
> php -m | grep dom
dom
```